# Is there a way to set up openapi examples in protobuf?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, prism, openapi

I am using [gnostic](https://github.com/google/gnostic) to output `openapiv3` yaml files from `protobuf`.
Furthermore, I am setting up a Mock server from openapiv3 using [Prism](https://meta.stoplight.io/), but I want to use the response from the examples specified.
Is there a way to set up examples in protobuf and output them to openapiv3 in a format that can be used with prism's mock?

I want to output openapi yaml like this from protobuf.

```
responses:
  '200':
    description: OK
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          '$ref': '#/components/schemas/Pet'
        examples:
          cat:
            summary: An example of a cat
            value:
              id: 2
              name: Fluffy
          dog:
            summary: An example of a dog
            value:
              id: 1
              name: Spot
```

Comment: can you clarify your question,  are you already generating open api v3 yaml from protubuf `.pb` files or are you looking for a way to do it.

Comment: yes, I have already generated open api v3 yaml

Comment: `prism mock` of the generated yaml. should give the expected mock server.